# Magento 2 Column names: "_super_attribute_price_corr" are invalid

Tags: magento2, import, csv

I'm trying to do a Magneto 1 to magneto 2 import, using the built in Magento 2 importer. I keep receiving the error "Column names: "_super_attribute_price_corr" are invalid". Did the attribute name for _super_attribute_price_corr update?

Thanks,

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The column `_super_attribute_price_corr` indeed does not exist any more. For good reasons: In M1, pricing for configurable products worked like this:

- price of configurable product with selected option 1 = price of configurable product + surcharge for selected option 1
- price of configurable product with selected option 2 = price of configurable product + surcharge for selected option 2
- ...

In M2, pricing for configurable products works like this:

- price of configurable product with selected option 1 = price of respective **simple** product
- price of configurable product with selected option 2 = price of respective **simple** product
- ...

Hence, there are no surcharges for specific variations any more. That is why the column `_super_attribute_price_corr` has no meaning any more and is not respected any more. In order to import your price in M2 correctly, you have to set the final sale price on the respective simple product. The configurable product does not have any price at all.